# jQuery - disable select option based on option keyword not by value

Tags: jquery, html, select, disabled-input

I have this HTML select code:

```
​<select name="loc_code">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="loc1">Loc1 status ON</option>
  <option value="loc2">Loc2 status ON</option>
  <option value="loc3">Loc3 status OFF</option>
  <option value="loc4">Loc4 status ON</option>
</select>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

So, I have a problem disabling option drop downs based on the text name not by value. I need to disable only options that contains status OFF.

I tried to modify this jQuery code from other posted similar questions on StackOverflow, but obviously it is wrong:

```
$("select[name="loc_code"] option:selected").text(function() {
  var $thisOption = $(this);
  var valueToCompare = "OFF";

  if($thisOption.val() == valueToCompare) {
    $thisOption.attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
});​
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you are wrapping a double quote inside of a double quote in the first line, could that be your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not do:

```
$('select[name=loc_code] option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('OFF') >= 0) $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pxD7U/)**

Comment: Perfect, it works. Thank you so much. I can't stop surprising how quick some people can write code, that I have to spend hours, not able to figure out and then go for help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector

```
$('select[name="loc_code"] option:contains(OFF)').prop('disabled',true);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CALe7/

Comment: Yup :)  No need to even loop